# spherical Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to find the first few terms in the spherical Bessel functions of the $1^{st}$ kind and am not getting the third term correct.

$j_l(kr)=\left(\frac{-r}{k}\right)^l\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^lj_{0}(kr)$,

and

$j_{0}(kr)=sinc(kr)=\frac{sin(kr)}{kr}$.

If $k=1$, and $l=2$, I am getting the following:

$j_2(r)=r^2\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\left(\frac{sin(r)}{r}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{r^3}\left((r^2-2)sin(r)+2rcos(r)\right)$.

But it should be

$j_2(r)=\frac{3sin(r)}{r^3}-\frac{3cos(r)}{r^2}-\frac{sin(r)}{r}$.

When I graph both solutions, they do not have the same roots. I am making a mistake but I can't see where...

Comment: The differential operator, $r D_{r}$, is to be seen as $(rD_{r})^{p} = (r D_{r})\cdots (r D_{r})$ (p-times). In the course of what you are obtaining it is seen as $(r D_{r})^{2} = r D_{r}( r D_{r}) = r [ r D_{r}^{2} + D_{r} ] = r^{2} D_{r}^{2} + r D_{r}$.

Comment: @Leucippus...thanks for the help, I appreciate your comment